# DRM initialised but dont work at ZOTAC with VIA ZX900 gpu

Tags: 16.04, xorg, drm, via, openchrome

I have ubuntu 32 bits.

My initial problem is freeze of xorg with

```
[    31.514] (EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:00:01.0: No such file or directory

message in Xorg.0.log file
```

xorg.conf is :

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "carte1"
    Driver        "openchrome" #    zotac
    BusID        "PCI:00:01:0"  # zotac
EndSection
```

Driver "vesa" works, but is limited to 1024x768 mode.

dmesg seems strange :

```
[    8.539958] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810

[   10.890285] EXT4-fs (sda1): ....
```

There are more 2 seconds between drm initialisation and the next message. And no others drm posts then. drm kernel module is not loaded, despite it is possible manually with modeprobe.

It seems drm have some special file to create and don't make them.

I've disabled dri module at xorg.conf, but xorg stay frozen.

Thanks for your help

---

It's the same without xorg.conf.

I really think it's drm issue. On my **thinkpad** dmesg says :

```
[   12.139863] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
....
[   12.188649] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   12.188657] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[   12.188659] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   12.188707] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
....
[   12.671103] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[   12.912612] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   12.912675] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
[   12.912706] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   12.912707] drm: registered panic notifier
[   12.914633] acpi device:00: registered as cooling_device4
[   12.914718] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   12.914759] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
[   12.914841] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
....
```

and I can find two special files :

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,  0 juin  18 13:42 card0
crw-rw----  1 root video 226, 64 juin  18 13:42 controlD64
```

ZOTAC's dmesg gives only drm initialisation message, without gpu initialisation massage, as at thinkpad's listing at `[   12.914841]`. The special dri files are not at ZOTAC, neither.

Comment: Have you try run it without `xorg.conf` file? Also, have you try to comment out «BusID» line? It should work without that line just fine.

Comment: Without xorg.conf it is the same. I really think it's drm issue. On my thinkpad dmesg says :[   12.139863] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810

Comment: Well, as everything should have worked even without `xorg.conf`, the best I can think of is to  report a bug. So, move `xorg.conf` off, boot until the freeze, and report a bug with attachments of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. I've heard VIA drivers just recently got a maintainer, until that [nobody could even merge patches](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OpenChrome-Maintainer-Hope). So probably you'd need to upgrade the kernel and drivers… Idk, but I think bug report is the best way to get them working sooner — perhaps devs would advice a workaround.